# What does the diff() function in R do?

Tags: r

I do not understand what the function `diff()` in R does. See this example:

```
 temp = c(10,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,10)
 diff(temp)
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
 [1] -9  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  7
```

What is the definition of this function?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot undderstand the concept behind it.

Comment: What is the application, and how the results are calculated?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The function calculates the differences between all consecutive values of a vector. For your example vector, the differences are:

```
 1 - 10 = -9
 1 -  1 =  0
 1 -  1 =  0
.
.
.
 3 -  1 =  2
10 -  3 =  7
```

---

The argument `differences` allows you to specify the order of the differences.

E.g., the command

```
diff(temp, differences = 2) 
[1]  9  0  0  0  0  1 -2  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  5
```

produces the same result as

```
diff(diff(temp))
[1]  9  0  0  0  0  1 -2  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  5
```

Hence, it returns the differences of differences.

---

The argument `lag` allows you to specify the lag.

For example, if `lag = 2`, the differences between the third and the first value, between the fourth and the second value, between the fifth and the third value etc. are calculated.

```
diff(temp, lag = 2)
[1] -9  0  0  0  0  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  2  9
```

Comment: What does the argument "differences" do?

Comment: @user1885733 See the update of my answer.

Comment: @user1885733 If you call `diff(x)` without the arguments `lag` and `differences`, the default values (i.e., 1) will be used. This is the same as `diff(x, lag = 1, differences = 1)`.

Comment: Also see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/diff

Answer (score 21):

It computes the difference between pairs of consecutive elements.

Let's say `temp` are observations of some variable, for example temperature readings taken on the hour. Then `diff(temp)` will tell you how much the temperature has changed during every hour.

The opposite of `diff()` is `cumsum()` (cumulative sum):

```
> temp
 [1] 10  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3 10
> cumsum(c(10, diff(temp)))
 [1] 10  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3 10
```