# Difference between neighbouring elements of a vector

Tags: r, loops

I have no idea how to solve an introductory exercise to R, so the exercise is

> Create a vector z with all 99 differences between the neighbouring elements
> of x such that z[1]=x[2]-x[1], z[2]=x[3]-x[2], . . .

I guess it is supposed to work without loops.

Comment: search for `?diff` and may be this can help.                       [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911486/the-diff-function

Comment: I am not able to try since I just started with R and have really no clue. Therefore I am basically thinking what it could be. I was thinking of creating a vector including the increasing indices but i guess this doesn't solve the iterating problem. I also googled for iterating without loop and i always encountered the function sapply() But I didn't get what it actuall does.

Comment: The problem as you describe it does not match the title of your post.  Perhaps a better title might be something like 'difference between neighboring elements of a vector'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sounds like diff function

```
diff(x)
```

You can also use this code:

```
x[-1] - x[-length(x)]
```

`x[-1]` - vector x without first element

`x[-length(x)]` - vector x without last element

Comment: Yeah that's true. Really sounds like diff(x) but since this functon wasn't introduced in the course I guess there has to be a quite basic straight forward approach to this exercise?

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot for your help. I guess that's what was aked for.

Comment: 3 years later this is great help :)

Answer (score 6):

```
x <- c(1,3,3,9) 
(z <- x[-1] - head(x, -1))
# [1] 2 0 6
```

Comment: Well yeah! I haven't thought of that...Great. Thanks alot

Comment: @lukeA I liked your answer