# Divide each element of a vector by the next

Tags: r, function

Is there an analogous function to [diff()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911486/the-diff-function), which divides successive elements instead of finding the difference?

```
x = c(10,8,4,-1)
some_function(x)
# [1]  1.25  2.00 -4.00
```

Comment: appreciated, but equally, why build your own when there is one possibly available?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with an explicit loop here, e.g. `tail(x,-1) / head(x,-1)`, or do the indexing directly with `[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's something like that available in base R. But you can try creating your own solution such as

```
unlist(sapply(2:length(x), function(i) x[i-1]/x[i]))
# unlist (sort of) takes care of when x has less than 2 elements
```

OR

```
x[-length(x)]/x[-1]
```

Comment: Part of my preference for the second approach is that your `sapply` solution falls down when `x` is of length 0.

Comment: @joran Or length 1, when it becomes `sapply(2:1, ...)`

Comment: @Frank, I think `unlist` takes care of that

Comment: @d.b Well, not in a way that is consistent with diff. `diff(1)` is an empty vector; while `your_fun(1)` is a length-one NA. I think it would be desirable for the result to be reliably of length `length(x)-1L`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `dplyr` is using `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
lag(x)/x

#[1]    NA  1.25  2.00 -4.00
```

If you want to remove `NA` just do

```
y = lag(x)/x
y[-1]

#[1]  1.25  2.00 -4.00
```